# Attachments file ATT00001.txt

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

Can you help me fix this please ?
When I send an e-mail, I receive my attachments but with a supplement called ATT00001.txt

```
// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// header for attachment 
$header.= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n"." boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n"."--{$mime_boundary}\n"."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n".$message."\n\n"; 
$message.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";


  //Ajout des pieces jointes si il y en a
  if(!empty($attach)){
    foreach($attach as $pj){
      $file = fopen($pj,"rb");
      $data = fread($file,filesize($pj));
      fclose($file);
      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
      $fileName = basename($pj);
      $message.= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n"." name=\"$pj\"\n"."Content-Disposition: attachment;\n"." filename=\"$fileName\"\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n".$data."\n\n";
      $message.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";    
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your final MIME boundary should have `--` *after* it in addition to before it, to indicate that it is the last one. Without it, an unlabelled extra part appears at the end, containing nothing, and this is typically treated as an unnamed attachment and given some sensible default by your email client - in this case, assigning it an incrementing filename and treating it as a plain text file.

Comment: If I put a -- to $message.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; I no longer receive attachments, it's normal ?